# trying to log out of facebook, then logging back || however it logs me back in automatically when I press the login button

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey I have a login button in my app.

this is the code I use to logout:

```
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
        self.presentWithStoryBoard("LoginController")
```

but when I try to login again, it doesn't ask for my credentials and it logs me in automatically.

Is there a way to remove whatever is prompting it to log me in automatically? I want to use someone elses credentials

Comment: You are only allowed to have one Facebook account. Why do you need to login as someone else?